# "cannot move out of borrowed content" for Vec but not u64

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, borrow-checker

The following code throws an error:

```
struct Foo {
    a: Vec<u64>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn change_a(&mut self, new_a: Vec<u64>) {
        self.a = *choose(&self.a, &new_a);
    }
}

fn choose<'a>(x: &'a Vec<u64>, y: &'a Vec<u64>) -> &'a Vec<u64> {
    return if x > y { x } else { y };
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { a: vec![1] };
    foo.change_a(vec![3]);
    println!("{:?}", foo.a);
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         self.a = *choose(&self.a, &new_a);
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

[This code works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=023a7879295c6b7d6cc93d556efed52a&version=stable&backtrace=0) if I replace the `Vec<u64>`s with just `u64`s.

What is the difference?

Comment: Maybe something to do with the vector element's lifetime being separate from the vector itself?  i.e. each vector elem needs to have a lifetime at least as long as `self.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive type `u64` implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). This means that `u64` has "copy semantics": if the compiler finds that we are trying to take ownership of `T: Copy` but the value being moved from is still used, `T` will be copied.

`Vec` is not `Copy`, but it is `Clone`, meaning that we can do

```
self.a = choose(& self.a, & new_a).clone();
```

To fix this problem.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d5912a0bf746f05141a43bba025731c5&version=nightly&backtrace=0) is another example of copy semantics using your example

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `u64` implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) while `Vec<u64>` does not. When you try to move a value of a type that implements `Copy` but the value being moved from cannot be moved, the compiler will not actually move it, but will copy it instead, which is why the version with `u64` compiles fine.